# I use launchwebauthflow to OIDC authenticate, but Chrome does not save password and login

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When using chrome.identity.launchwebauthflow, Chrome does not save login and password. When opening same link directly in Chrome, it offers to save login and password, but non when it is opened in popup of chrome.identity.launchwebauthflow. Is there a way to save credentials in popup of launchwebauthflow?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=907920), so built-in launchwebauthflow does not support sessions. I used library to polyfill launchwebauthflow with [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create).[This](https://github.com/eight04/webext-launch-web-auth-flow) one for example.